# android username password input

Tags: android

I need to accept values (username and password) from the user, when he clicks menu button and one of the button that says login. When the login button is clicked, a pop up should show up that accepts the values and should have an ok button.
Expecting a pop something like when we try to download an app from apple store (iphone)
Could some one please guide me how to do this. Also... this menu is to be visible for a MapActivity class which implements LocationListener

thanks

Comment: I did not quite got you what you mean, you have User/Password screen and you want to put a login menu button then pops a dialog that ask you wether you input was correct or not??

Comment: nope... is there a way to create a menu kinda thing when a menu button is pressed..that accepts username and password...

Comment: Not a question, and there are tons of tutorials out there that do literally exactly this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial should be enough for you to get started, just change the custom dialog XML layout to two edit texts.
[Tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application)

Comment: .. hey thanks...could you please provide me with a tutorial of creating menu option. Also, is it possible to create menu options for a map activity?